# Facebook at Canvas(apps.facebook.com) or Fanpage

Tags: facebook, facebook-apps, facebook-page

As title, how can I check if I'm landed on facebook Canvas page or fanpage tab?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the [`signed_request`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/signed-request/) for whether it contains a `page` property or not.

Comment: does it mean if we land on apps.facebook.com we wouldn't find page in the signed_request array(after decrypt)

Answer (score -1):

```
if(strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], 'apps.facebook')) {
  echo 'canvas page';
}
```

Comment: This is a bad idea - the client does not have to send a genuine referrer, nor does it have to send one at all.